# Unwanted return from JavaScript functions with DOM

Tags: javascript, function, dom, return

I am designing a JavaScript function **checkForm()**, which is meant to check if at least half of the answers of a form have been completed. It returns ”true” if the condition is met and an alert message and ”false” if not. The answers are given in input text fields, whose content mustn't be the empty string in order to be regarded as answered.

In order to make the check, the function **checkForm()** calls two other functions: **totalNumberOfQuestions()** and **totalCompletedAnswers()**, as follows:

```
            function totalNumberOfQuestions() /* Returns the total number of questions in the form */
            {   total
                    numberOfQuestions = 0;

                    i = 1;

                    do
                    {
                            nameOfAnswer = 'answer_' + i;

                            if(document.getElementsByName(nameOfAnswer)[0] != null)
                            {
                                    totalnumberOfQuestions ++;
                            }
                    i++;
                    }
                    while (document.getElementsByName(nameOfAnswer)[0] != null);

            return totalnumberOfQuestions;
            }



            function totalCompletedAnswers() /* Returns the total number of completed answers in the form */
            {   
                    numberOfCompletedAnswers = 0;

                    i = 1;

                    for(i = 1; i<= totalNumberOfQuestions(); i++)
                    {

                            nameOfAnswer = 'answer_' + i;

                            if ( form[nameOfAnswer].value != '')
                            {
                                    numberOfCompletedAnswers ++;
                            }
                    }


            return numberOfCompletedAnswers;
            }




            function checkForm()  
            {

            if ( totalCompletedAnswers() < 7 )
                    {
                            alert("Please answer at least half of the questions.");
                            return false;
                    }

            return true;
            }
```

But, surprisingly, the function **checkForm()** does not work correctly in this form, but returns true even when the number of completed answers is less than a half of the total number of answers. However, the function works properly if the function **totalCompletedAnswers()** is checked against a constant value, e.g.:

```
            function checkForm()  
            {

            if ( totalCompletedAnswers() < 7 )
                    {
                            alert("Please answer at least half of the questions.");
                            return false;
                    }

            return true;                        
            }
```

This means that using the function **totalNumberOfQuestions()** in the body of the **checkForm()**  function is ”importing” some unwanted returned value. This happens even if I call the former separately (*x= totalNumberOfQuestions()* and then rewriting the condition: *if ( totalCompletedAnswers() < x )*
). Does anyone know how one can avoid such unwanted returned values when calling a function?

Comment: Did you check what totalNumberOfQuestions() returns?

Comment: @ Pilatus - The function totalNumberOfQuestions() returned the total number of questions and the returned value hs always been correct. I wonder if it does not return a ”true” value after doing it, and thus ”deceiving” the evaluation in the checkForm() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `totalComletedAnswers` you have the snippet:

```
if(numberOfCompletedAnswers  < totalNumberOfQuestions() )
{
      alert("Please answer at least half of the questions.");
      return false;
}
```

So `totalCompletedAnswers` will return false if all the answers are not completed **not** the number of questions answered.

In `checkForm` the the following will evaluate to true: `false < 7`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5mURZ/

Have a look at these two articles for more information on truthiness/falsiness in javascript:

- http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript
- http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

**UPDATE**

Upon closer inspection you have a scoping issue. All your variables have a global scope. This will cause the most issues with the variable `i`. Declaring the variable with the `var` key word will restrict the scope of the variable to the function. It is best practice in javascript to delvare **all** variable with the `var` keyword to explicitly declare the scope of the variable.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dr5Hx/1/

Article on scoping: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

**Update 2**

For a completely different approach, try the magic of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This approach relies on wrapping the answers in some kind of container. In this case a `div`. This is required as elements such as check boxes and radio buttons would be multiple elements, but each set should only be counted once.

```
//The selector below finds DOM elements  with a name beginning with "answer"
var answers = $("[name^='answer']"); //'Cache' answers
var answerDivs = $("div").has("[name^='answer']"); //'Cache' answer divs
var totalAnswers =  answerDivs.length; //'Cache' number of answers

$("#checkIt").click(function(){ //Add a click listener to the button
    var numAnswered = $(answerDivs).filter(function(){ //Filter our answer divs to answered question
    var answer = $(this).find("[name^='answer']");  //Get the answer element(s) in the div
    var textCheck = $(answer).is("input:text") && $(answer).val() != ''; //Check For Text Value
    var selCheck = $(answer).is("select") && $(answer).val() != ''; //Check for selected 
    var radioCheck = $(answer).is(":checked"); // Check for Checked, WOrks for radio & checkbox
    //console.log($(answer).attr("name") + "  " + textCheck + " " + selCheck + " " + radioCheck)
    return (textCheck || selCheck || radioCheck); //End of the filter
    }).length;

    if(numAnswered < (totalAnswers/2))
    {
        alert("Please answer atleast half the questions");
        return false;
    }

    alert("We're good to go");
    return true;

});
```

Just make sure to wrap the above in [`$(document).ready();`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

http://jsfiddle.net/Dr5Hx/3/

Comment: @ Jon P That snippet was a typo which occurred when I pasted the code to this page. So, it was not a part of the function. If it had been it would have definitely been the cause. I am sorry for the mistake, I have removed the snippet.

Thank you for the websites, they are really relevant. The page jsfiddle.net is very practical, too.

Comment: @ Jon P Thank you so myck, Jon. Indeed, it was the scope of the variables that caused the problem. In fact, it was not the `i` but the other two variables that proved to be the cause: `totalnumberOfQuestions` and `numberOfCompletedAnswers`. The problem disappeared after declaring them local, using `var`. Thank you for the jQuery alternative too. I have used jQuery on the same page, though not for checking the form but for displaying messages with `fadeIn()`. The `filter()` function seems to be very useful.

Comment: @ Jon P Sure! Done. The accept worked, but for the vote up I got the answer ”Vote Up requires 15 reputation”, whereas I only have 3 at this stage. So I will vote again as soon as I get the credits from the website.